# How to retrieve checkbox options and add to database using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am attempting to add some checkbox options to my database via LINQ entities as one item. However the roadblock i run into is that i get an error trying to add these as into one variable to add to the db. Here is what i have so far:

```
 public string GetSelectedItems(CheckBoxList control)
    {
        var items = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (ListItem item in chbxRoomChange.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
                items.Append(string.Format("{0},", item.Text));
        }
        return items.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
    }
```

adding to db:

```
var choices = GetSelectedItems(chbxRoomChange);
 rc.preference = choices;
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()

Comment: @Robertpurpose I have edited my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the exception details you have posted then I suspect the column you are inserting into the database is too small to hold the data you are passing from your application.

Debug your app and see what length of the string returned by `GetSelectedItems` is and then compare that with the size of the column you are inserting into. I suspect you will find your string just won't fit and you need to increase it's size.

As a side note you could rewrite your method to use 1 line:

```
var choices = string.Join(",", chbxRoomChange.Items
                                             .Cast<ListItem>()
                                             .Where(li => li.Selected)
                                             .Select(li => li.Text)
                                             .ToArray());
```